# Gradle DSL method not found : 'compile()'

Tags: android

I have gone through almost all posts for this error. But i was unable for figure out the issue.
I have tried to change build.gradle repositories to mavenCentral() and have also tried make changes in app.gradle. I just though of adding volley into my app, from then the sync is getting failed.
I have also tried file->Invalidate caches/Restart.

I feel there is some problem with getDefaultProgaurdFile. as I can see it is underlined.
Please help me on this.
Thanks

```
                apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
            android {
             compileSdkVersion 23
             buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
             defaultConfig {
              applicationId "com.six30labs.cms"
              minSdkVersion 15
              targetSdkVersion 19
              versionCode 1
              versionName "1.0"
             }
             buildTypes {
             release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
              }
             }
            }
```

http://postimg.org/image/4kv7qh7cr/

http://postimg.org/image/azlbyum2b/

Comment: Please edit your question and post your `build.gradle` file as text.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo there. Change it and build again.

Use

```
getDefaultProguardFile()
```

Instead of

```
getDefaultProgaurdFile()
```

Comment: build.gradle...

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I found a solution for this one.
You will have to update your Android studio version. Just go t help -> check for update. wait until it prompts you to Update and Restart Android studio. After that If you sync gradle it will work fine and also if you are implementing Volley then just give as compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' (don't use -aar).
At last click on File->Invalidate caches/Restart.

you're Done!!